# Is there any way to see overall Ubuntu One sync progress?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, sync

I am very surprised to find that the U1 client only shows me "File Sync in Progress".

I can see the current transfers and files still to be transferred (in an uninformative flat list) with

```
u1sdtool --current-transfers
```

and

```
u1sdtool --waiting
```

But neither of these give a % completed or time estimate based on current transfer speed. I seem to recall that this feature existed in much earlier version of the U1 client.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that does the same as --status and doesn't give a progress indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the Ubuntu One Indicator Applet. Just run :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-ubuntuone
/usr/lib/indicator-ubuntuone/indicator-ubuntuone
```

See also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2042684

This didn't work for me so well, but maybe it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

We will find out the "deflated size" and "bytes written" with

```
u1sdtool --current-transfers
```

Then, you can calculate the percent.